# the toast is not showing in bootstrap 5 even though no error in developer tools

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5, toast

why is the Toast not showing in the code below? I'm using bootstrap 5. I haven't the slightest idea why because there isn't any errors in the developer's tools. any help is appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Page Template</title>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fontawesome-5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Page</h1>

    <!-- Your content here -->
    <div id="toast-sticky-message" class="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3" style="z-index: 1500000">
        <div class="toast">
            <div class="toast-body">
                <span id="toast-content"></span>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        function makeAlertElem(string, id = false, replace = false, color = "alert-info", timeout = 5000,
            dismissable = true) {
            let toastElement = document.getElementById("toast-sticky-message");
            if (!toastElement) {
                return false;
            }
            console.log("toast string", string);
            toastElement.querySelector("#toast-content").innerHTML = string;
            let toast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastElement);
            console.log("toast 2", toast);
            toast.show();
        }
        // end function makeAlertElem

        makeAlertElem('hello world');
    });


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This could depend on where you are putting the script. Show us that and we could easier help you i guess...

Answer (score 2):

It's because the Toast is initialized with the wrong element. You should target the element with class `toast` :

```js
function makeAlertElem(string, id = false, replace = false, color = "alert-info", timeout = 5000,
  dismissable = true) {
  let toastElement = document.querySelector("#toast-sticky-message .toast");
  if (!toastElement) {
    return false;
  }
  toastElement.querySelector("#toast-content").innerHTML = string;
  let toast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastElement);
  toast.show();
}
// end function makeAlertElem

makeAlertElem('hello world');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<h1>Welcome to the Page</h1>

<div id="toast-sticky-message" class="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3" style="z-index: 1500000">
  <div class="toast">
    <div class="toast-body">
      <span id="toast-content"></span>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow thanks. I guess real people with real skill is still much better than chatgpt.. I consulted with it for hours and still no correct solution, while I only had to wait like 10 minutes here and the first answer is already correct.